# Deploy WebService on Tomcat: WS not available: 404 Error

Tags: web-services, tomcat, soap

This is my first frist question in stackoverflow! WOW :)

I'm losing my hairs on this issue :(
I have a simple helloworld-Web Service, and build the warfile and deploy it on tomcat (8.0.35) at localhost. 
To be clear: I just wrote a class, annotated with @WebService; Then I wrote web.xml and sun-jaxws.xml; I did not do anything else! Is that enough for that class to become a Webservice? Do I miss another step?

Problem: The url: localhost:8080/endpointname/url-pattern  does not show me the definition of my Webservice as it is meant in the Link I followd to write the service: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/.  I just get a fat 404 Eror. This ist my buildfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="test_WS" default="deploy" basedir=".">
<property name="project-name" value="${ant.project.name}" />
<property name="war-file-name" value="${project-name}.war" />
<property name="source-directory" value="src" />
<property name="web-directory" value="WebContent" />
<property name="webinf.dir" value="${web-directory}/WEB-INF" />
<property name="web-xml-file" value="${webinf.dir}/web.xml" />
<property name="build-directory" value="build" />
<property name="shared.deploy.dir" value="C:/1_Entwicklung/datarocket/tomcat-webapps" />
<property name="local.deploy.dir" value="C:/1_Entwicklung/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/webapps" />

<tstamp prefix="build-info">
    <format property="current-date" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" locale="de" />
    <format property="current-time" pattern="hh:mm:ss a z" locale="de" />
</tstamp>

<!-- Classpath -->
<path id="build.classpath">
    <!-- Jax WS related -->
    <fileset dir="${webinf.dir}/lib/" casesensitive="yes">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>  
</path>

<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${webinf.dir}/classes" />
    <mkdir dir="${build-directory}/classes" />
</target>

<!-- deploy -->
<target name="deploy" depends="war">
    <copy file="${build-directory}/${war-file-name}" todir="${local.deploy.dir}" />
    <copy file="${build-directory}/${war-file-name}" todir="${shared.deploy.dir}" />
</target>

<!-- war  -->
<target name="war" depends="build">
    <war warfile="${build-directory}/${war-file-name}" webxml="${web-xml-file}">
        <classes dir="${build-directory}/classes" />
        <fileset dir="${web-directory}">
            <!-- exclude webxml as it is attribute of the war tag -->
            <exclude name="WEB-INF/web.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Built-On" value="${build-info.current-date}" />
            <attribute name="Built-At" value="${build-info.current-time}" />
        </manifest>
    </war>
</target>   

<target name="build" depends="clean">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${source-directory}" destdir="${build-directory}/classes">
    </javac>
</target>


<!-- clean --> 
 <target name="clean" description="Prepare for clean build">
    <delete dir="${webinf.dir}/classes" />
    <delete dir="${build-directory}" />
    <mkdir dir="${build-directory}" />
    <mkdir dir="${build-directory}/classes" />
</target>
</project>
```

This is my sun-jaxws.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0"> 
    <endpoint   
        name="HalloAPI"
        implementation="saab.javabeans.Hallo"
        url-pattern="/sayhello" >
    </endpoint>
</endpoints>
```

And this is the API:

```
@WebService
public interface HalloAPI {
     String sayHello(String name);
}
```

Why does tomcat say: "HTTP Status 404 - /HalloAPI/sayhello" ?
Something wrong or missing concerning publishing?
I mean, if I use glassfish-server, it deploys and show me the tester- and wsdl.
But with deploying on tomcat... I get 404.

Here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<display-name>test_WS</display-name>
<listener>
<listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>webservicesServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.Servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>webservicesServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/sayhello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
 <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

Happy I: I moved the required jaxws jars  into web-inf/lib. Now Tomcat does not throw errors on deploy time. But the service vial url still not available. What I know: jaxws-jars in tomcat/lib are confusing the classloader. So I packed them into war.
Here is now the deploying protocoll:

```
07-Jun-2016 15:34:54.149 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\1_Entwicklung\apache-tomcat-8.0.35\webapps\test_WS.war
07-Jun-2016 15:34:55.371 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.<init> WSSERVLET14: Initialisierung von JAX-WS-Servlet
07-Jun-2016 15:34:55.372 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized WSSERVLET12: Initialisierung von JAX-WS-Kontext-Listener
07-Jun-2016 15:34:55.373 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized WSSERVLET12: Initialisierung von JAX-WS-Kontext-Listener
07-Jun-2016 15:34:55.385 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\1_Entwicklung\apache-tomcat-8.0.35\webapps\test_WS.war has finished in 1,236 ms
```

Problem remains: service not available; status: 404 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: do you see anything in the logs ? and can you also add your web.xml file ? try this link http://localhost:8080/test_as_WS/sayHello

Comment: But... sayHello is the methodname not the url-pattern.Why shall I try that?

Comment: I mean lower case localhost:8080/test_as_WS/sayhello

Comment: I get allways the same error. I think there is a step that I dont go through. But I don't know which. How can I ask tomcat to list all webservices registerd?

Comment: did you server come up ? did you miss copying sun-jaxws xml over ?

Comment: It does start up. But with lots of warnings. I attached the server warnings above.thanks

Comment: were you able to access your site ? do you see any errors apart from warnings ? You dont have to copy the jars into tomcat lib directory. They should be packaged with the application.

Comment: I moved the libs to web-inf/lib. Tomcat deploys. But still no 404.:(

Comment: your server seems to have started fine. I think you are just using wrong url to access the web service. I was able to access the same set up locally. Can you try url localhost:8080/test_WS/sayhello ?

Comment: What do you mean by "able to access the same set up"?

Comment: I mean I used your set up, tweaked the build script little bit so that it packages the dependencies into the war and it worked for me. Those are not server warnings they you have attached, they are just debug logs. Did you try the with the above url ? You can check your tomcat admin manager for right context path of your application. Can you add your implementation class to the post ?

Comment: Do you work with tomcat 8.0.35, jdk 1.8.0_91, in eclipse? Does Tomcat need also catalina-ws.jar? Could you please show your tomcat/lib? The mentioned path test_WS/sayhello had not worked also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.**S**ervlet.WSServlet to
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.**s**ervlet.WSServlet in your web.xml

Comment: That was absoulte madness from me. Three days for a capital letter S!  I am so happy! Thank you Shiv :)